# Safe to remove pilot cover for water heater?

Tags: water-heater, pilot-light

I'm having problems get my water heater to heat. The first thing, I imagine, is to make sure the pilot light is lit. I've tried a few times, but no luck. It doesn't help that I can't see the pilot light. The instructions say there's a glass port where you can see it. If there is one, it's covered by this plate that has anti-tamper screws.
Is it safe to remove these and see the pilot light?

[image]

[image]

Seems to be a GG50T06AVH00 from GE:
https://www.geappliances.com/appliance/GE-Gas-Water-Heater-GG50T06AVH00

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure removing *that* cover (on the gas control valve/thermostat) is the *wrong* thing to do. Suspect you might be misinterpreting where to look, (the pilot is usually much further inside the heater, near the main burner) but you have not shared the make & model of your water heater.

Comment: The pilot light NOT being inside this box is strongly supported by the igniter and thermocouple wires leading down and in. Follow them. Or [edit] to share the make and model and someone else can point out from the manual where you should be looking. That appears to be below this and deeper inside.

Comment: Thanks. I've uploaded that, and the instructions which describe the 'sight glass' and 'inner door' and 'outer door'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The "outer door" is **below** the "thermostatic gas valve." Labeled "jacket door" in this diagram from earlier in the manual. Take **that** off and have a look for the pilot assembly. Do NOT disassemble the "thermostatic gas valve."

The "inner door" and its sight glass will be located INSIDE the "outer door"  - NOT out in the open on the face of the "thermostatic gas valve." As is clearly noted, you should not attempt to remove the "inner door", either.

[image]

Images are from the manual found at the web page (now) linked in the question.

Comment: Many thanks. It would have been nice to have that picture with the lighting instructions, or have it refer to "cover plate" as the 'jacket door" shown in the diagram.
There's no problem lighting with the pilot but it won't stay on after 5-10 minutes  (goes out when switching from pilot mode to on). Guess I need a technician. It 14 years old. I imagine they're recommend  replacement.